# What is the best free setup/install builder?

Tags: python, installation

So I am working on a project for university and my team and I are looking into a solution to build an installer for our project. We have developed an desktop application and need to be able to put an install package on a usb drive, and install everything from the drive to ubuntu desktops when the user double clicks on the install file.

We have looked into InstallBuilder, however they don't offer a free option, and we do not have the money to pay for a software at this point. So my question is, does anyone know of a good alternative that is free that would allow us to package our code, libraries and dependencies to a file that could be deployed on a desktop via usb?

(Not sure if it is relevant, but our project is written in python.)

Comment: Read the docs - https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html

Comment: There's also this - https://packaging.python.org/distributing/ Both are free and can be used to create `*.msi` packages etc. I'm assuming you're on windows.

Comment: @Torxed - ubuntu

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I am on a Mac for the development. Also I have read the docs, and am a bit confused, maybe you could shed some light. So because I only need this to run on a linux machine, I should be creating an RPM package?

Comment: Is this a pure-python package? Build a [wheel](http://pythonwheels.com/). You could also just build a .deb package which is native for ubuntu.

Comment: @tdelaney, not pure-python, we have embedded some matlab code for graphing functionality.

Comment: For ubuntu, you want .deb.

Comment: You can add non-python data files to a wheel, for instance, if you want your python program to grab the matlab files and use them. They end up in the python libraries directory along with the module. Wheels are built by creating a `setup.py` file and it sounds like they will work for you. Some lifting required, see https://packaging.python.org/distributing/

Comment: Once you have the wheel you can put it on a usb or even make it available on one of your servers via a url.